# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, terminal

I'm quite new to use the build and artifacts features. I have a program that reads a JSON file, evaluates it and return a different JSON file. After creating an artifact and built it, I go in the terminal in the same folder as the one where jar that I built (that I would call `programExample.jar` for example) is, and type in the terminal to launch the program.

> java -jar programExample.jar jsonToRead.json jsonOutput.json

The issue is that after typing this command, this error shows up:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 63.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I don't understand how I have to solve that and have been looking for a few hours now.

The project use `openjdk-19` and when typing `java -version` in the terminal, I have `java version "1.8.0_351"` and typing `javac -version`, I have

> javac : The term 'javac' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Would love to have an insight.

If needed, here is also my Maven file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Declarations</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what more insight you need. You're running an application with a version of Java that is a full 11 versions behind the version used to compile it.

Comment: That's where I'm struggling, I don't really quite understand what I have to do. I am not that familiar with these yet

Comment: Install a more recent version of the JDK/JRE.

Comment: I may have missed something because I did install Java SE Development Kit 19.0.1 an hour ago

Comment: Then you need to make sure that you correctly set your JAVA_HOME environment variable and that the Java executable is on your path.